# fill None's in data frame using nested if statement python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my dataframe. Here i am trying to fill none values in columns using multiple if conditions . But the code I tried is not working.

```
import pandas as pd 

# intialise data of lists. 

data = {'Region':['APAC', 'EMEA', 'EMEA', 'APAC'], 'Country':['Germany', 'None', 'UK', 'India'],'Site':['None', 'None', 'None', 'Goldhill']} 

# Create DataFrame 

df4 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df4
```

I tried below one: but getting an error:

```
  if (df['Region'] != None and df['Country'] == None and df['Site'] == None):
        df['Country','Site'] = 'Region_Access' 
    elif (df['Region'] != None and df['Country'] != None and df['Site'] == None):
        df['Site'] = 'Country_Access'
    else : 
        df['Country','Site'] = 'No_Data'
    ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().




   Expected output :

data = {'Region':['APAC', 'EMEA', 'EMEA', 'APAC'], 'Country':['Germany', 'Region_Access', 'UK', 'India'],'Site':['Country_Access', 'Region_Access', 'Country_Access', 'Goldhill']} 

# Create DataFrame 

output = pd.DataFrame(data)  
output
```

Comment: Note that the question leaves out an important detail - OP is asking about "None" values, but is referring to the literal string "None", not Python's built-in null value None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you what's wrong here.

You have an if statement with a series as an input. A series might be large, and multiple entries can satisfy or not satisfy the statement, so it's not really parsable. It's not a 'True' or 'False', some entries satisfy that condition and others don't. That's why if statements require you to get a bool out of the series (any, all, .empty,...).

Now that the issue is clear, how can you solve it?
With Dataframes or series, you have to think more of "sub-filters" in these situations.

Basically, I have my whole Dataframe, and I select subsets of the data according to what I want. I end up with a smaller Dataframe that satisfies my conditions, and I do operations on that.

More amazingly, pd allows you to select just subsets of the Dataframe and do operations on those. So you're not editing the smaller df, you can actually edit entries in the original one. This is part of the indexing power (there's a lot that you can do with loc and iloc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

To choose the right entries, you can select them with bools inside loc (as other answers mention), so

```
(df['Region'] != 'None') & (df['Country'] == 'None') & (df['Site'] == 'None')
```

is basically a dataframe row-bool-index that is true for rows where the condition is satisfied and false where it isn't. You feed that into loc:

```
df.loc[(df['Region'] != 'None') & (df['Country'] == 'None') & (df['Site'] == 'None')]
```

This selects the part of your Dataframe that satisfies those conditions. Now you pick which columns you want to change, by adding them as another index to loc. The statement (similar to other answers):

```
df.loc[(df['Region'] != 'None') & (df['Country'] == 'None') & (df['Site'] == 'None'),['Country','Site']] = 'Region_Access'
```

basically says, change the 'Country' and 'Site' columns for rows that satisfy that condition to 'Region_Access'.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `loc` indexer:

```
df.loc[(df['Region'] != 'None') & (df['Country'] == 'None') & (df['Site'] == 'None'), ['Country','Site']] = 'Region_Access' 
df.loc[(df['Region'] != 'None') & (df['Country'] != 'None') & (df['Site'] == 'None'), 'Site'] = 'Country_Access'

df
>>>
  Region        Country            Site
0   APAC        Germany  Country_Access
1   EMEA  Region_Access   Region_Access
2   EMEA             UK  Country_Access
3   APAC          India        Goldhill
```

or you can use `df.fillna()` or `df['colname'].fillna()`